# How Do I add a RecycleBin to a newly formatted NTFS flash drive

Tags: recycle-bin

New thumbdrives often come formatted as FAT or FATex drives.  When I reformat them as NTFS drives, the RecycleBin is gone.  How do I add it back in?

Comment: Windows seems to manage this automatically. The recycle bin is not a component of the flash drive. It’s something Windows creates. Have you tried putting a file on the flash drive and deleting it? You may also not see the recycle bin because it’s typically a hidden folder.

Comment: I deleted a file that was on the thumbdrive.  I got a message asking if i wanted to permanently delete the file.  I clicked yes..  No $RECYCLE.BIN appears in the File Explorer window, as it does with the other drives, and when I open the Recycle Bin icon on my desktop, it shows deleted files from other thumbdrives, but not the file I just deleted from this drive.
There is no data yet on this drive.  Maybe I can reformat it a different way?

Comment: *I got a message asking if i wanted to permanently delete the file. I clicked yes.* EVERYTHING that happens after this was normal and expected, that's what "permanently" means, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to right click the recycle bin icon on your desktop and select "properties".

There, you can see what drives (and partitions) it is being used for.

Example: On my current setup, all internal disks are listed there. Also, an usb HDD (not a stick) that's connected is listed and using it. But a connected SD Card is not shown there, so it could not use the recycle bin.

You might be able to activate it for USB drives tweaking the registry of your Windows system. **Do that carefully**, fiddling around in the registry also can harm your system. This guide is written for Windows 11, but for Windows 10 it's the same thing, https://winaero.com/how-to-enable-the-recycle-bin-on-removable-drives/

1. Press the Win + R shortcut, and type regedit in the Run dialog box.
2. Open the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
3. In the right pane, right-click the empty space and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value and name the new value RecycleBinDrives.
4. Finally, double-click it and set the RecycleBinDrives value data to ffffffff in hexadecimal.
5. Restart Windows to apply the change.